# Stored Procedures and Functions missing from Schema navigator in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-workbench, stored-functions

All the Stored Procedures and Functions are missing from my schema navigator, yet i have inspected the Database and they're all there! If it might help, i have recently added the following line `lower_case_table_names=2` to `my.ini` configuration file to make the database/table names case-sensitive.
I am using windows 8, thanks.

Comment: Is this a question about a GUI tool to handle MySQL databases? If so, which one?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I am using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by commenting out the `lower_case_table_names=2` line i have added previously to the configuration file.